# Cookie value undefine in javascript

Tags: javascript, cookies

I have created text input field where the user whatever types in is set as the cookie value. I created two functions Readcookie() and Writecookie();As the user clicks on the button, the consequent functions are triggered. While the Writecookie works fine but Readcookie() show the name as well as value of cookie as undefined. My code is as follows:

```
<script>
function WriteCookie()
{
   if( document.myform.customer.value == "" ){
      alert("Enter some value!");
      return;
   }

   cookievalue= escape(document.myform.customer.value) + ";";
   document.cookie="name=" + cookievalue;
   alert("Setting Cookies : " + "name=" + cookievalue );
}
function ReadCookie(){
    var allcookies=document.cookie;
    var cookiearray=allcookies.split(';');
    for(i=0;i<cookiearray.length;i++){
        var name = cookiearray[i].split('=')[0];
        var  value = cookiearray[i].split('=')[1];
        alert("Key is : " + name + " and Value is : " + value);
    }   
}
</script>
<form name="myform" action="">
Enter name: <input type="text" name="customer"/>

<input type="button" value="write Cookie" onclick="WriteCookie()"/>
<input type="button" value="read Cookie" onclick="ReadCookie()"/>
</form>
```

Comment: Pasted your code into a blank html page and it works. No problem here. Maybe you have cookies disabled?

Comment: Wiorks fine in jsfiddle, too: http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/r5psb3c6/

Comment: yes i tried and it worked all again, thank you